# Having difficulties in installing tensor flow

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

I keep on getting this message whenever i try installing tensor flow usx the pip command

My OS is windows

Comment: Does your C: drive has space left?

Comment: Delete some stuff and try again